# Volume of Group SO(3, R) endowed with a Killing metric

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, tensors

Got this question from Modern Geometry Part 1 (Dubrovin, Fomenko, Nokinov).
No idea how to start. I'm looking for the simplest, most dumbed down solution with most things explained. It may be the case that this problem is a bit above my level. The problem is placed at the end of a section "...the Theory of Integration". I assume I need to use the Killing metric and the "volume element" tensor and integrate over all parameters of SO(3)?

Comment: The volume of $S^3$ is $2\pi^2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere. $SO(3)$ is has $S^3$ as its double-cover, so to compute its integral of any 3-form over it, in particular, its volume form with respect to its Killing metric (so that the exponential map WRT its Lie group structure is its exponential map WRT its Riemannian manifold structure are the same and scaled so one gets the "correct" volume for the double-cover), one can lift the form to the double-cover, integrate there, then divide the result by 2. Hence, the volume of $SO(3)$ is $\pi^2$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

**Some guidance, rather than a complete answer**

Suppose you have two tangent vectors at the identity (i.e. you have a pair of $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices).

1. Can you explain why these are tangent vectors at the identity?
2. Supposing that one has entries $a_{ij}$ and the other has entries 
   $b_{ij}$, what's the inner product of $a$ and $b$ under your metric?

You may recall that to measure the length of an arc $c$, you compute
$$
\int_a^b \|c'(t)\| ~dt
$$
while to compute the area of a surface (in 3-space) you compute
$$
\iint \| \partial S/\partial u (u, v) \times \partial S/\partial u (u, v) \| ~du ~dv
$$

In each case, you parametrize the object, and then integrate over the parameter domain. But there's an alternative. Suppose that your curve is actually a closed curve, and you have a map 
$$
s: S^1 \to \Bbb R^2 : t \mapsto s(t)
$$
with the properties that (1) \|s'(t)\| is constant, $c$ and (2) $s$ is a 3-to-1 map. If only it was a 1-to-1 map, you'd know that the length of your curve was exactly $c$ times the length of the unit circle, i.e., $2\pi c$. But because it's a 3-to-1 map, the length of the curve must be $\frac{2}{3}\pi c$. Clever, hunh?

OK. Well, the natural covering map from $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ actually has constant volume-change factor, and it's a 2-to-1 map. So if you knew (a) the volume-change constant, and (b) the volume of $S^3$, then you'd have an answer.

Thinking of $S^3$ as the space of unit quaternions, the tangent space at $q = 1$ is spanned by the three vectors $i, j,$ and $k$. You'll need to figure out what the volume form on that tangent space, applied to those three vectors, gives. (Hint: the answer is $1$).  Those vectors correspond, under the covering map, to three rotation matrices, the matrices for the maps 
$$
x \mapsto i^{-1} x i \\
x \mapsto j^{-1} x j \\
x \mapsto k^{-1} x k \\
$$
defined on the 3-dimensional space of pure-vector quaternions (i.e., no real part). If you apply the volume form on SO3 to those three matrices, you'll get some number $c$. And then the volume of $SO(3)$ is just $c$ times the volume of $S^3$, divided by $2$ because the covering map is 2-to-1.

Full disclosure here: I've never actually performed this computation. But this is how I'd go about it...

**Post-comment addition**

Thinking of $S^3$ as unit quaternions, and $\Bbb R^3$ as pure-vector quaternions, there's a map
$$
p : S^3 \to L(\Bbb R^3, \Bbb R^3) : q \mapsto (x \mapsto q^{-1} x q ).
$$
The map $p$ takes a unit quaternion and converts it into a linear map on the vectorspace of pure-vector quaternions. Picking a basis $b_1 = i, b_2 = j, b_3 = k$ lets us map the space of such linear maps to the set of $3 \times 3$ matrices, thus defining a map  $P: S^3 \to SO(3)$.  For instance, as you observe, $$
P(i) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1}.
$$
More importantly, $P(1)$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Furthermore, $p$ can be extended to define a map on all of $\Bbb R^4$ (using the same formula, or if you want to avoid inverses, replacing $q^{-1}$ with $\overline{q}$); naturally, this extends $P$ as well, although the resulting matrices, for $q \notin S^3$, are generally not orthogonal, so we get a new map -- let's call it $N$, with 
$$
N: \Bbb R^4 \to M_{3,3} : q \mapsto C( x \mapsto \overline{q} x q),
$$
where $C$ is the function that takes a linear map on 3-space and converts it to the matrix for that map wrt the basis $i,j,k$. $N$ has the property that for $q \in S^3$, we have $N(q) = P(q)$.

That means we can use the derivative of $N$ (at $1$) to compute the derivative of $P$ (at $1$) -- just ignore the data in the non-$S^3$ direction!

Let's look at $dN(1)(i)$, the derivative of $N$ at the point $1 \in S^3$, in the direction $i$. We can start with a curve
$$
c(t) = 1 + ti
$$
passing through $1$ at time $0$; we have $c'(0) = i$, right?

Now look at $N(c(t))$. [This is the part where *you* get to do some work!] It's a matrix that depends on $t$. You take the derivative of that (to find a vector in the tangent space to $M_{3,3}$), and evaluate at $t = 0$ (to find a vector in $T_{I} M_{3,3}$); that vector (i.e., $3 \times 3$ matrix!) will be tangent to $SO(3)$ at the identity, i.e., it'll be skew-symmetric. And it'll be $dN(1)(i)$. Which means that it's *also* $dP(1)(i)$.

Now go through that all again for $c(t) = 1 + tj$, and $c(t) = 1 + tk$, and you'll have transformed a basis of $T_1(S^3)$ -- a basis that spans a unit volume! --  into a set of three vectors in $T_I(SO(3))$. Then you use your volume-measuring skills (something to do with the Killing metric!) to determine the volume of the cube that these three vectors span. That's your "change of volume" constant.

Comment: 1. One direction is differentiating the identity $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_{ij}a_{ik} = \delta_{jk}$ and setting $a_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. This shows that a curve of orthogonal matrices passing through the identity will have a skew-symmetric derivative at that point. The other direction is using X a skew-symmetric matrix, and computing $(1+tX)(1+tX^T)$ and approximating at small $t$, showing that $A(t) = 1 + tX$ is a line that passes through the orthogonal matrices and has derivative X at the identity.
2. Using $<A,B> = tr(AB^T)$, I get $2(a_{12}b_{12}+a_{23}b_{23}+a_{13}b_{13})$ for skew symmetric A, B.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the "natural covering map"?
I also get lost when finding those matrices. Say $x = ai+bj+ck$. Then $i^{-1}xi = ai-bj-ck$, so the corresponding matrix would be $\diag(1,-1,-1)$, and this is an element of SO(3) but not of its tangent space (which it seems like I need).

Comment: See post-comment additions.

Comment: So now I've caught up to the end. I've found the derivatives in the directions of $i,j,k$. For instance, the one in the direction of $i$ is $\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -2 & 0}$. But now, I'm unsure of how to utilize the metric. It is clear that since this is a basis, the inner product of two of these matrices gives 0. However, I can see how the matrices I got should give me the value of $c$ I need, namely 8, since the textbook gives a basis for so(3,R), and the matrices I get are these matrices scaled by -2. But I'm not sure how to get this result using the metric.

Comment: Well...your question mentions the "volume element tensor"; do you know what that actually *is* (and in particular, what it is at the point $I \in SO(3)$)? Also: when they gave a basis for $so(3)$, did they show it was orthonormal?

Comment: Here's what I've got from thinking about the problem. At first I was trying to create a parallel to the idea of finding a determinant which gives you the change in volume in a linear transformation. Then I thought about using cross products which didn't seem to be available. But the Lie bracket (i.e. commutation) acts as an "outer product". So here's what I did: Denoting the matrices in the direction of $i,j,k$ as $I,J,K$, I computed $[J,K] = JK-KJ$, and then used the inner product $<I, JK-KJ> = tr(I(JK-KJ)^T).$ Then this result needs to be scaled by |I| = 2 (using the typical vector norm).

Comment: This gives me -8, but I assume I can place an absolute value for safeguarding. This gives the volume of $SO(3,R)$ to be $8\pi^2$. I'm not sure if my line of reasoning was correct or if I just forced my answer.
To answer your questions, I understand that in $SO(3)$ we would have $\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon_{i_1i_2i_3}$ as the elements of the tensor. I haven't computed the metric $g_{ij}$, but I suppose I would use the inner product and the basis for $so(3,R)$. They did not show the basis was orthonormal, but that the relations $[X_1,X_2]=X_3$ etc make it isomorphic to 3-vectors under the cross.

Comment: " I assume I need to use the Killing metric and the "volume element" tensor and integrate over all parameters of SO(3)?" doesn't seem consistent with "I haven't computed the metric $g_{ij}$". It's time to do some computations!

Comment: The book gives a basis for so(3). One element is $X_1 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0}$. Using the inner product $tr(XY^T)$ gives $g_{ij} = <X_i,X_j> = 2\delta_{ij}$. But the 2 doesn't seem right to me. This gives $g=8$. Now you say to "apply the volume form" and get some number. Maybe I'm not understanding what exactly is the volume form, but I don't see how I can get a number out of 4 matrices.